# Access ASHX from URL without .ashx extension

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, url-routing, ashx

I have a Web handler in an ASP.Net project. I want to access it from the URL.

Yes, I can do it like
http://mywebsite.com/handler.ashx?id=35157
It works fine.

But the problem is, I'm accessing it from some Arduino devices. Their libraries do not support that kind of URLs.

They support http://mywebsite.com/handler?id=35157 like URLs.

**How can I access the web handler from URLs like http://mywebsite.com/handler?id=35157,device=DF,Msg=OK**

Without the ASHX extension in it?

Comment: You'll have to create a custom route handler. [This blog has an example of this.](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/mar/28/custom-aspnet-routing-to-an-httphandler)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use an IIS rewrite rule.

```
<rule name="Remove ASHX Extension" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^handler(.*)$" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="handler.ashx{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a handler in Web.config:

```
 <handlers>
        <add name="CustomHandler" path="handler" verb="GET" type="AppCode.CustomHandler" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
  </handlers>
```